# Find total of all variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to find a way to find total base salary, total commissions, and overall total paid to all employees in the department in this problem. So far, I have this as the code:

```
employee = str(1)

numbemployee = input('How many employees are there in your department? ')

while numbemployee < str(0):
    print('The number of employees cannot be less than zero!')
    numbemployee = int(input('How many employees are there in your department? '))

while employee <= numbemployee:
    name = str(input('What is the name of employee ' +employee +'? '))
    employee = str(int(employee) + 1)
    totalyears = int(input('How many years has ' +name +' worked for the company? '))
    while totalyears < 0:
        print('The number of years worked cannot be less than zero!')
        totalyears = int(input('How many years has ' +name +' worked for the company? '))
    if totalyears <= 6:
        base_salary = 10000.00
        print('The base salary for ' ,name ,' should be $' ,base_salary)
    elif totalyears <= 13:
        base_salary = 14000.00
        print('The base salary for ' ,name ,' should be $' ,base_salary)
    elif totalyears <= 20:
        base_salary = 18000.00
        print('The base salary for ' ,name ,' should be $' ,base_salary)
    elif totalyears <= 34:
        base_salary = 27000.00
        print('The base salary for ' ,name ,' should be $' ,base_salary)
    else:
        base_salary = 30000.00
        print('The base salary for ' ,name ,' should be $' ,base_salary)
    sales = float(input('What was ' +name +"'s sales for the last quarter? "))
    while sales < 0:
        print('The sales cannot be less than zero!')
        sales = float(input('What was ' +name +"'s sales for the last quarter? "))
    if sales <= 3999.99:
        commission = 1000
        print(name ,'earned $' ,commission ,'from commission for sales from last quarter')
    elif sales <= 11999.99:
        commission = 2000
        print(name ,'earned $' ,commission ,'from commission for sales from last quarter')
    elif sales <= 15999.99:
        commission = 5000
        print(name ,'earned $' ,commission ,'from commission for sales from last quarter')
    elif sales <= 23999.99:
        commission = 8000
        print(name ,'earned $' ,commission ,'from commission for sales from last quarter')
    elif sales <= 27999.99:
        commission = 12000
        print(name ,'earned $' ,commission ,'from commission for sales from last quarter')
    else:
        commission = 15000
        print(name ,'earned $' ,commission ,'from commission for sales from last quarter')
    totalwage = base_salary + commission
    print(name ,'should recieve $' ,totalwage ,' for this quarter.')
```

I am unable to find the total base salary for all employees in the department. Same for finding the total commission and total pay for all employees. Does anyone know how I might do this??

Comment: why are you casting your input to int, and then comparing it to `str(0)`? Also maybe look into turning `employee` to a class or at least a dictionary...

Comment: This "question" needs to be refined. What are you trying to do? What is the pseudo code?  What is happening that you do not expect?

Comment: Might be able to turn this into a useful question with a simplified example and an explanation of what you have tried.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of issues with your code-  which is fine, this is clearly a learning problem.

In order to sum up all the base salaries, bonuses, etc., you will have to create an *accumulator* variable for these sums. Right now, you have variables for the details of the employee. You need to add some *more* variables to handle accumulating totals from one employee to the next:

```
accum_total_salary = 0
accum_total_commission = 0

while ...

    base_salary = ...

    commission = ...

    accum_total_salary += base_salary
    accum_total_commission += commission
```

Finally, outside the loop, when you're done processing all the worker info, you can print your accumulated numbers:

```
print("Sum total salary paid to all employees:", accum_total_salary)
print("Sum total commission paid to all employees:", accum_total_commission)
```

Comment: A huge part of why the code doesn't work is incorrectly casting things to `str` that are supposed to be numerical.